# Images not linking in Gollum wiki

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, gollum-wiki

I have images in the same directory as the `.md` files:

```
...
...
test.md
test.png
to-do.md
balter@bcore:/var/www/B-Core-Collaboration.wiki$
```

My source looks like this:

```
![](test.png)
```

I have also tried

```
![](/test.png)
```

But the image is not showing up.

The generated page source has:

```
<img src="test.png" alt="" />
```

or

```
<img src="/test.png" alt="" />
```

Comment: Have you tried a relative link using `[[test.png]]` or `[[./test.png]]`?

Comment: @GabrielOshiro I guess I should try that. According to [this](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#images) page, I'm using the correct format for images in github markdown. However according to [this](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-images-to-wikis/) page, I should use what you suggested. A bit confusing...

Answer (score 1):

It is working with gollum 5.3.0 when gollum is started with command line option --allow-uploads (in case you use gollum from within a docker container, you have to put it after the container image so that it is interpreted as parameter for gollum).

After this, you can drag and drop the image on the edit field of gollum.

No reason to copy the image files manually to your repo. The repo should be managed by git alone.

Details on command line options can be found here: https://github.com/gollum/gollum#configuration